# Javascript - Add an error msg when xml is unavailable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, optimization

I've built an iPhone app that's working great so far.  I've had some great help here optimising the code, but wondered if I could please obtain some help to display an error msg when the following conditions are met.

1. When the **xml file is unavailable**
2. When one of the **xml data fields is missing** (eg. brisbane is currently not listed in the xml for function 1, but should be - http://www.arpansa.gov.au/uvindex/realtime/xml/uvvalues.xml)

**My current code:** http://pastebin.com/VgBmdXjd

At the moment I've got the error msg working when the **xml data field is empty** (not missing), which should be apparent in the code. Please let me know if it isn't.

Also, both functions are setup a little differently, which might affect the way the condition is formatted.  If anyone is able to explain the differences, that would be great too.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Glen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the [ajax error event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) handler in jQuery. [Good Example](http://www.maheshchari.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling/)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Do you have anything on the ability to error msg a missing set of xml fields?